# Did I correctly calculate this complicated limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

The general term of the sequence is:

$$a_n=\left[\frac{1}{3} + \frac{n^{1000}}{2^n}\right]^n$$

My solution so far:

$$\begin{align}
a_n&=\left[\frac {1}{3}\left(1 + \frac{3n^{1000}}{2^n}\right)\right]^n\\
&=\left[\frac {1}{3}\left(1 + \frac{3}{\frac {2^n}{n^{1000}}}\right)^{\frac{n^{1000}}{2^n}}\right]^n\\
\end{align}$$

Then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n= \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^ne^{3n}=\left(\frac{e^3}{3}\right)^n=\infty$$

Is it correct?

Comment: @Integrator: I guess, by complex OP meant difficult.

Comment: Sure, but I changed the title for better clarity.

Comment: No. Consider that $\frac{n^{1000}}{2^n} < \frac{1}{n}$ for large enough $n$, so your limit cannot be larger than that of  $\left[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{n}\right]^n$ which is definitely finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is incorrect, because you inserted an exponent of $n^{1000}/2^n$ in passing from the first to the second line in your solution.

The limit is zero, as can be seen by first noting that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{3} + \frac{n^{1000}}{2^n} = \frac{1}{3},$$
so that there exists some $N > 0$ such that $n \ge N$ implies $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{n^{1000}}{2^n} \le \frac{2}{3}.$
Then we can bound your limit above: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{n^{1000}}{2^n}\right)^n \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n = 0$$
and the result follows by the squeeze theorem.